# Unexpected child metadata error[CustomObjectTranslation]

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-sfdx

I am trying to retrieve Apex classes or anything from sandbox Org to my local system with VS code then I am getting follwoing error

```
Unexpected child metadata [\force-app\main\default\objectTranslations\SomeObjectNameHere-en_US\parent_account.fieldTranslation-meta.xml] found for parent type [CustomObjectTranslation]
```

I started getting this error when I tried to retrieve custom object translation into local system then I tried to retrieve another thing also getting same errors,Can you please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a same issue and resolved it recently. The only difference was in my case it was a deploy and and in your case its a retrieve. May be this could solve your issue

The xxx.objectTransalation-meta.xml file was not present due to which it was throwing an error. Create a file give the exact name(Transalation Object Name) to it. This should resolve the error

Please refer to below snapshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoB3Q.png)